# Batch File Compare (FC) Output Not Working

Tags: batch-file, cmd, file-comparison

I have two files that contain a list of files from a directory: files.txt and filesb.txt
file1.txt contains the following:

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
file5
file6
filelast
```

While filesb.txt contains:

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
file5
file7
filelast
```

From what I understand, the following batch code:

```
FC C:\Users\[username]\Desktop\files.txt C:\Users\[username]\Desktop\files.txt
```

Should output this:

```
Comparing files C:\USERS\[username]\DESKTOP\files.txt and C:\USERS\[username]\DESKTOP\FILESB.TXT
***** C:\USERS\[username]\DESKTOP\files.txt
file6
***** C:\USERS\[username]\DESKTOP\FILESB.TXT
file7
*****
```

but instead outputs this:

```
Comparing files C:\USERS\[username]\DESKTOP\files.txt and C:\USERS\[username]\DESKTOP\FILESB.TXT
***** C:\USERS\[username]\DESKTOP\files.txt
file5
file6
filelast
***** C:\USERS\[username]\DESKTOP\FILESB.TXT
file5
file7
filelast
*****
```

What can I do to only output the different files and not the surrounding ones as well? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try with `/b` option to see differences in hex format.There could be additional spaces or tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The first and last line of each set of differences is useful to correctly identify each set. If just the different lines were reported you may have problems to identify the line if the files were large and have many differences. However, you may get the output from FC command and process it in any way you wish, but this solution is not simple because there may also be insertions of new lines, deletions of old lines, or any combination of these cases.

Some time ago I wrote such a program that not only correctly process all these cases, but also allows a visual comparison of both files horizontally, using half the screen for each one. For example:

```
C:\> type files.txt
file1
file2
file3
file4
file5
file6
filelast

C:\> type filesb.txt
file1
file2
file3
file4
file5
file7
filelast

C:\> FComp files.txt filesb.txt
Comparando archivos files.txt y FILESB.TXT

==============================  SECTION MODIFIED  =============================

file5                                  |file5
file6                                  |file7
filelast                               |filelast

C:\>
```

You may download FComp.bat program from [this site](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3968). You may easily modify this program in order to supress the display of the first and last lines of each "Modified Section".

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest

```
findstr /x /v /L /g:file1 file2
```

which should output any lines in file2 that don't exist in file1.